# How to print JSON values in javascript fetched using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have made a js file in which data is being fetched from js file and the values are stored in a request object. Example of JSON file

```
{
    "name": "ABC",
    "age": 20
}
```

I want to display the value of name using variable name. I want something like this.

```
var x = "name";
var req = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
console.log(req.x);
```

But the above statement displays undefined. Any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use brackets instead of dot:

```js
var x = "name";
var req = {
  "name": "ABC",
  "age": 20
};

console.log(req[x]);
```

You need to use brackets here because the name of the property is dynamic, with the value coming from a variable (dot should be used only when the name of the property is static)

Answer (score 1):

It should be `console.log(req[x]);`

OR

```
console.log(req.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use obj[key]

```
console.log(req[x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `console.log(req.name)`